# Data transfer between rs and android?

Tags: android, renderscript

i am working with render script. i want to pass elements of an array to render script and 
want to perform the squaring of each element in render script and get back the data to 
android frame work.

I am trying to do this by following codes .

1.java code 
2.RS code

But via these code this thing is not possible.will u plz tell me what r errors i m doing 
with these codes.

============================================================================

## java code

```
  public class SUM extends Activity {


private int[] input;
private int[] output;
private RenderScript mRS;
private Allocation mInAllocation;
private Allocation mOutAllocation;
private ScriptC_Sum mScript;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    input= new int[4];
    input[0]=0;
    input[1]=1;
    input[2]=2;
    input[3]=3;

    output =new int[4];

    createScript();
}


private void createScript() {

    mRS = RenderScript.create(this);

    mInAllocation    = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.U32(mRS),4);
    mOutAllocation   = Allocation.createTyped(mRS,mInAllocation.getType());
    mScript = new ScriptC_Sum(mRS, getResources(), R.raw.sum);

    mScript.bind_v_in(mInAllocation);
    mScript.bind_v_out(mOutAllocation);

    mScript.invoke_square(mInAllocation,mOutAllocation);


}
}
```

===========================================================
RS CODE

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.cdacb.mars.summation)

#include "rs_types.rsh"
#include "rs_graphics.rsh"
#include "rs_core.rsh"

int32_t *v_in ;
int32_t *v_out;

 void square(){

}

void root(int32_t *v_in,int32_t *v_out )
{

   square();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1- I find out that your .rs file cannot have the same name as your .java file

2- you declared a output variable on your root function (*v_out) but never compute it inside the function.

3- Your java arrays are all ints. From the power function declaration on the [Renderscript API](http://developer.android.com/reference/renderscript/rs__cl_8rsh.html#a9243de1d67fcc847a89f95748d664b19), they all take at least a float as input

Here is my java code:

```
    public class Sum extends Activity {
    private float[] input;
    private float[] output;
    private RenderScript mRS;
    private Allocation mInAllocation;
    private Allocation mOutAllocation;
    private TextView t1;
    private ScriptC_Square mScript;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sum);
        t1= new TextView(this);
        t1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        input= new float[4];
        input[0]=0;
        input[1]=1;
        input[2]=2;
        input[3]=3;
        output =new float[input.length];
        createScript();
    }

    private void createScript() {
        mRS = RenderScript.create(this);

        mInAllocation    = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.F32(mRS),4);
        mOutAllocation   = Allocation.createTyped(mRS,mInAllocation.getType());
        mScript = new ScriptC_Square(mRS, getResources(), R.raw.square);

        mInAllocation.copyFrom(input);
        mScript.forEach_root(mInAllocation, mOutAllocation); // calls the forEach function to operate on the root function (each allocation input, will have a corresponding allocation output
        mOutAllocation.copyTo(output); // copy the result that was stored in mOutAllocation into the array output

        t1.setText(String.format("Input:%s\n\noutput:%s",
                                    ArrayToString(input), ArrayToString(output)));
    }


    /**
     * this function just print each element of a primitive float array into a text string
     * @param array
     * @return
     */
    public String ArrayToString(float[] array){

        String s="";
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            s+= String.format("\nValue %d: %f", i, array[i]);
        }

        return s;
    }

}
```

Here is my Square.rs file:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.sum)//don't forget to change that package name

void root(const float *v_in, float  *v_out ){

    *v_out = pow(*v_in, 2); //use the internal pow function of Renderscript pow(float x, float y) = x ^y;

 }
```

Comment: If you want to keep using int instead of float, you can just do "return *v_in * *v_in;". In your code above, you would also want to switch to 2.f instead of just 2, since that would imply a double->float conversion (one of the worse aspects of the C99 language).